# Why does status code 201 not work for a redirect?

Tags: php

I write a php application and want to do a redirect. It took me a long time to search, to find out that it works, when I remove the status code. My Code is:

```
http_response_code(201);  
header('Location: http://address/that/works/');
```

According to the documentation 201 should work.

> https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php
> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless **the 201 or a 3xx status code** has already been set.

And also, at least the german Wikipedia says:

> https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Statuscode
> Die Anfrage wurde erfolgreich bearbeitet. Die angeforderte Ressource wurde vor dem Senden der Antwort erstellt. **Das „Location“-Header-Feld enthält eventuell die Adresse** der erstellten Ressource.
>
> Translation:
> The request was processed successfully. The requested resource was created before the response was sent. **The “Location“ header field may contain the address** of the created resource.

Why does 201 not work?

Comment: What exactly does "work" and how does it "not work" exactly? What is the problem/issue you have when set or don't set the HTTP status?

Comment: When I set the status to 201 the Browser does no Redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the HTTP standard or in what you've included that says that the user agent should redirect the client to the location given in  `Location` header. Just that it contains the location of the created object. The 3xx series however is explicit about the content having moved, and that the client should look elsewhere.

In general you'll handle the 201 `Location` header in your own code and perform whatever action you want depending on the content - there is nothing inherent that says that the browser should retrieve (or display) the content that has been created - in many cases it shouldn't (i.e. a background request, etc.).

Use an explicit redirect if you want the client to redirect the user to a new location - that's what it's for.